# Can one encrypt an n-digit number, returning a unique n-digit number?

Tags: javascript, encryption

StackOverflow warns me that I may be down-voted for this question, but I'd appreciate your not doing so, as I post this simply to try to understand a programming exercise I've been posed with, and over which I've been puzzling a while now.

I'm doing some javascript coding exercises and one of the assignments was to devise an "encryption function", `encipher`, which would encrypt a 4-digit number by multiplying it by a number sufficiently low such that none of its digits exceeds 9, so that a 4-digit number is returned.  Thus

```
encipher(0204)
```

might yield

```
0408
```

where the multiplier would have been `2`.  -- This is very basic material, simply to practice the Javascript. --  But as far as I can see, the numbers returned can never be *deciphered* (which is the next part of the exercise).  Even if you store a dictionary internal to `encipher`, along the lines of

```
{'0408':'2'}, etc
```

so that you could do a lookup on `0408` and return `0204`, these entries could not be assured to be unique.  If one for example were to get the number `9999` to be deciphered, one would never know whether the original number was `9999` (multiplied by 1), `3333` (multiplied by 3) or `1111` (multiplied by 9). Is that correct?  I realise this is a fairly silly and artificial problem, but I'm trying to understand if the instructions to the exercise are not quite right, or if I'm missing something.  Here is the original problem:

*Now, let's add one more level of security. After changing the position of the digits, we will multiply each member by a number whose multiplication does not exceed 10. (If it is higher than 10, we will get a two-digit multiplication and the code will no longer be 4 values).  Now, implement in another function the decrypter (), which will receive as an argument an encrypted code (and correspondingly multiplied in the section above and return the decrypted code.*

Leaving the exercise behind, I'm just curious whether there exists any way to "encrypt" (when I say "encrypt", I mean at a moderate javascript level, as I'm not a cryptography expert) an n-digit number and return a unique n-digit number?

Thanks for any insights. --

Comment: Your encryption holds a key, this is used to encrypt and decrypt, in your first example your key is 2, you take it and multiply each number by 2, to  decrypt you could then use division by 2, the only issue I can see popping up is what happens if a digit is > 4 ? Then it would create a number with more than 1 digit.

Comment: If you're gonna post a puzzle question, I'd suggest posting the puzzle in its original form.

Comment: a rot5000 version of rot13?

Comment: @IngoBürk, Thanks.  I edited the post to include the original question.

Comment: @RyanWilson: yes, exactly, but to be usable with any number, the multiplier has to be 1, which sort of obviates the entire thing…so that's why I'm confused.  It's just a programming exercise, of course, but it got me curious if there were a way to do it...

Answer (score 2):

> encrypt a 4-digit number by multiplying it by a number sufficiently low such that none of its digits exceeds 9, so that a 4-digit number is returned

If your input is 9999, there is no integer other than 1 or 0 that you can multiply your input by and get a positive number with a maximum of 4 digits. Therefore, there is no solution that involves only integer multiplication. However, integer multiplication can be used as part of an algorithm such as rotating digits (see below).

If instead you're looking for some sort of bijective algorithm (one that uniquely maps A to B and B to A), you can look at something like rotating the digits left or right, reversing the order of the digits, or using a unique mapping of each individual digit to another. Those can also be mixed.

**Examples**

Rotate

1234 -> 2341

Reverse

1234 -> 4321

Remap digits e.g. 2 mapped to 8, 3 mapped to 1

2323 -> 8181

Note that none of these are cryptographically sound methods to encrypt information, but they do seem to more-or-less meet the objectives of the exercise.

Comment: Sadly, a question edit makes it clear multiplication is a requirement. V. strange, arguably off-topic question at this point...

Comment: Thanks.  The first part of the exercise (which I omitted as it was clear to me how it worked and _that_ it worked) was a rotation.  The next part was the multiplication.  Then after that comes a dictionary lookup which I also understood.  The only part I didn't quite see how (or why) it would work was the multiplication.